# How to pass Map of Serializable object as JSON in request body

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, postman

Model classes looks like this MailFilterCondition has map of EmailCondition where Filter is a class and MailAttributes and Operator are enums:

```
public class EmailCondition implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5429392022485346125L;
private Filter.MailAttributes key;
private Filter.Operator op;
private String value;

public Filter.MailAttributes getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(Filter.MailAttributes key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public Operator getOp() {
    return op;
}

public void setOp(Operator op) {
    this.op = op;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "EmailCondition [key=" + key + ", op=" + op + ", value=" + value + "]";
}
}

public class MailFilterCondition implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2691329267596354267L;
private int automationId;
private Map<String, EmailCondition> emailConditionMap;
private String filterString;

public int getAutomationId() {
    return automationId;
}

public void setAutomationId(int automationId) {
    this.automationId = automationId;
}

public Map<String, EmailCondition> getEmailConditions() {
    return emailConditionMap;
}

public void setEmailConditions(Map<String, EmailCondition> emailConditionMap) {
    this.emailConditionMap = emailConditionMap;
}

public String getFilterString() {
    return filterString;
}

public void setFilterString(String filterString) {
    this.filterString = filterString;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MailFilterCondition [automationId=" + automationId + ", emailConditions=" + emailConditionMap
            + ", filterString=" + filterString + "]";
}
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/email")
public void createAutomationFilter(@RequestParam(value="automation_id") int automationId, @RequestBody MailFilterCondition filterData) {

    System.out.println(filterData);
}
```

Request body:

```
{
"automationId": 123,
"filterString": "(c1_and_c2)_or_(c1_and_c3)",
"emailConditionMap": 
{
    "c1":{
        "key": "from",
        "op": "contains",
        "value": "jhon"
    },

    "c2":{
        "key": "from1",
        "op": "starts",
        "value": "ron"
    },

    "c3":{
        "key": "from",
        "op": "contains",
        "value": "payment"
    }
}
}
```

Filter enums:

```
public class Filter {
public enum Operator {
    contains("contains"), starts("starts"), ends("ends"), gt("gt"), gteq("gteq"), lt("lt"), lteq("lteq"), eq("eq"),
    inlist("inlist"), pattern("pattern");
    private final String operator;

    private Operator(String opt) {
        this.operator = opt;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.operator;
    }
}

public enum MailAttributes {
    from("from"), to("to"), subject("subject"), body("body"), received_time("received_time");
    private final String attribute;

    private MailAttributes(String attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.attribute;
    }
}

public enum LogicOperator {
    AND("_and_"), OR("_or_");
    private final String operator;

    private LogicOperator(String opt) {
        this.operator = opt;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.operator;
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
MailFilterCondition [automationId=123, emailConditions=null, filterString=(c1_and_c2)_or_(c1_and_c3)]
```

While passing key-value pair in json the map attribute reamins null. I tried everything but every-time emailConditions prints null.

Comment: I think your attributes are mis-named somewhere, as your JSON contains attribute name `emailConditionMap` yet your output contains `emailCondition`.  As `emailCondition` attribute is not present in the input JSON, it's set to null. Or is this just a typo when formatting your code for SO?

Comment: I am constructing JSON for MailFilterCondition class so emailConditionMap should be used.

Comment: This may be a long shot, but... Try changing getter/setter from `setEmailConditions/getEmailConditions` to `setEmailConditionMap/getEmailConditionMap` so that the setter/getter method names match the variable name.

Comment: no not working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have proper getters/setters in the classes?
I am not sure what the `Filter` class is, but changing those two fields to String it is working perfectly. So the problem may be there.

Comment: Yes getter setter are there

Comment: added whole classes

Comment: I still cannot see `Filter.MailAttributes` and `Filter.Operator` which where I think the problem is since if you change those two to String it is going to work.

Comment: No they work fine individually, problem is with map.

Comment: Tried and you are right, I have tried a few things already, but I am not able to make it working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson) Marshalling. It will convert the object automatically before being sent in the request body.
Jackson uses getters and setters so your object must have them.

Answer (score 0):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/email")
public void createAutomationFilter(@RequestParam(value="automation_id") int automationId, @RequestBody MailFilterCondition filterData) {

    System.out.println(filterData);
}
```

Here in `createAutomationFilter` method you are passing `@RequestParam(value="automation_id") int automationId` as parameter, which is not correct as you sending all parameter in request body in Postman. So you have to map all parameter in one `Model` class (i.e MailFilterCondition) and by using
`@RequestBody` annotation. Please see the below controller.

Controller:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/mail")
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/create", produces = { "application/json" })
    public void createAutomationFilter(@RequestBody final MailFilterCondition emailConditionMap,
            final HttpServletRequest request) {
      System.out.println(emailConditionMap);

    }
}
```

In this model `MailFilterCondition` your setter and getter  for `emailConditionMap` field is not appropiate.

```
public Map<String, EmailCondition> getEmailConditions() {
    return emailConditionMap;
}

public void setEmailConditions(Map<String, EmailCondition> emailConditionMap) {
    this.emailConditionMap = emailConditionMap;
}
```

Update your setter and getter with (Spring used to map fields with exactly the same name of the field setters)

```
   public Map<String, EmailCondition> getEmailConditionMap() {
    return emailConditionMap;
     }

   public void setEmailConditionMap(Map<String, EmailCondition> 
     emailConditionMap) {
    this.emailConditionMap = emailConditionMap;
    }
```

Model: `MailFilterCondition`

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;

public class MailFilterCondition implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2691329267596354267L;
    private int automationId;
    private Map<String, EmailCondition> emailConditionMap;
    private String filterString;

    public int getAutomationId() {
        return automationId;
    }

    public void setAutomationId(int automationId) {
        this.automationId = automationId;
    }

    public Map<String, EmailCondition> getEmailConditionMap() {
        return emailConditionMap;
    }

    public void setEmailConditionMap(Map<String, EmailCondition> emailConditionMap) {
        this.emailConditionMap = emailConditionMap;
    }

    public String getFilterString() {
        return filterString;
    }

    public void setFilterString(String filterString) {
        this.filterString = filterString;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MailFilterCondition [automationId=" + automationId + ", emailConditions=" + emailConditionMap
                + ", filterString=" + filterString + "]";
    }
}
```

In model `EmailCondition`, i am passing `String` as param in

```
public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = Filter.MailAttributes.valueOf(key);
}

public void setOp(String op) {
    this.op = Filter.Operator.valueOf(op);
}
```

as you can see in request body you are passing `key` and `op` value as `String`, 
these value are not any kind of custom java class. At run time Spring could not figure out the type, which you passing

```
public void setKey(Filter.MailAttributes key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public void setOp(Operator op) {
    this.op = op;
}
```

as per my knowledge, you can also bind these fields using `@InitBinder` annotation.

Model: `EmailCondition`

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import com.spring.web.controller.Filter.MailAttributes;
import com.spring.web.controller.Filter.Operator;

public class EmailCondition implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5429392022485346125L;
    private Filter.MailAttributes key;
    private Filter.Operator op;
    private String value;

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = Filter.MailAttributes.valueOf(key);
    }

    public void setOp(String op) {
        this.op = Filter.Operator.valueOf(op);
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MailAttributes getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public Operator getOp() {
        return op;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EmailCondition [key=" + key + ", op=" + op + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }
}
```

Model: `Filter`

```
public class Filter {

    public enum Operator {
        contains("contains"), starts("starts"), ends("ends"), gt("gt"), gteq("gteq"), lt("lt"), lteq("lteq"), eq(
                "eq"), inlist("inlist"), pattern("pattern");
        private final String operator;

        private Operator(String opt) {
            this.operator = opt;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return this.operator;
        }
    }

    public enum MailAttributes {

        from("from"), to("to"), subject("subject"), body("body"), received_time("received_time");
        private final String attribute;

        private MailAttributes(String attribute) {
            this.attribute = attribute;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return this.attribute;
        }
    }

    public enum LogicOperator {
        AND("_and_"), OR("_or_");
        private final String operator;

        private LogicOperator(String opt) {
            this.operator = opt;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return this.operator;
        }
    }
}
```

You can send ajax request as below:

```
var payLoad = {

                "automationId": 123,
                "filterString": "(c1_and_c2)_or_(c1_and_c3)",
                "emailConditionMap": 
                {
                    "c1":{
                        "key": "from",
                        "op": "contains",
                        "value": "jhon"
                    },

                    "c2":{
                        "key": "to",
                        "op": "starts",
                        "value": "ron"
                    },

                    "c3":{
                        "key": "subject",
                        "op": "ends",
                        "value": "payment"
                    }
                }

           };

    $.ajax({
        url: appContextJs+"/mail/create",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(payLoad),
        success: callbackfunction
    });
```

appContextJs: as your base URL e.g: `http://localhost:8080/webapp`

Please do not forget to set `contentType` as `application/json` in Postman

Postman console output:

```
{
    "automationId": 123,
    "emailConditionMap": {
        "c1": {
            "key": "from",
            "op": "contains",
            "value": "jhon"
        },
        "c2": {
            "key": "to",
            "op": "starts",
            "value": "ron"
        },
        "c3": {
            "key": "subject",
            "op": "ends",
            "value": "payment"
        }
    },
    "filterString": "(c1_and_c2)_or_(c1_and_c3)"
}
```

Eclipse console output:

```
MailFilterCondition [automationId=123, emailConditions={c1=EmailCondition [key=from, op=contains, value=jhon], c2=EmailCondition [key=to, op=starts, value=ron], c3=EmailCondition [key=subject, op=ends, value=payment]}, filterString=(c1_and_c2)_or_(c1_and_c3)]
```

Comment: That is not a solution, that is changing the implementation! :)

Comment: in the beginning he didn't provide the whole code, i will modify the code

Comment: Is it working for you now that you edited the code?

Comment: @DilipChauhan are there any changes in model or controller classes?

Comment: @quintin Hold on I will explain, is this solve your problem?